# XDocument.Load method does not exist in XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm stuck at loading a new XML document with Linq. That's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XDocument doc = new XDocument.Load("001.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in return is that 'Load' method does not exists on type 'XDocument'.
It's really weird because I thought that "using System.Xml.Linq" was enough.
I wanted to use Linq because I have a complex XML and I think it's easier to navigate through all elements with Linq. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Solved, I'm just a dummy. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4):

[`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method. Your code isn't syntactically correct - you're seemingly attempting to call a constructor (by using `new`), but you're missing some brackets.

To call a static method, it's simply this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("001.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299692(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `static` method of `XDocument`. Your code tries to instantiate a new `XDocument` object (at `new XDocument()`) and call `Load` as its instance method.

Change your code to this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("001.xml"); // without "new"
```

Answer (score 1):

XDocument.Load is a static method, simply use it this way (without the new):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("001.xml");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition, For `static` method of `XDocument`

```
 var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("./wwwroot/resources/createwebsite.xml");
```

For `XmlDocument`

```
  var xmld = new XmlDocument();
  xmld.Load("./wwwroot/resources/createwebsite.xml");
```